# GWT Drag and drop

Tags: java, gwt

I created a simple application:

```
public class GWTDradAndDrop implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        verticalPanel.setSpacing(10);
        verticalPanel.add(new DrugButton("test"));
        RootPanel.get().add(verticalPanel);
    }
}
```

`DrugButton` class:

```
public class DrugButton extends Button {

    private static DrugButton dragging = null;

    public DrugButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        setWidth("200px");
        initClick();

    }

    private void initClick() {
        addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("dsdsdsa");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Tell me how can I add a drag event to this widget (button)?

Comment: You might want to check on the name of your button. I'm not sure I want to be pushing your button the way that it is named now.

Answer (score 0):

You need add handlers to your button for a set of drag events.

Here the documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#addDragHandler-com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DragHandler-

And here a bunch of demos about drag and drop, hopefully seeing some code will make the issue more clear: https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com/